# PRCE: substring exclusion in capturing group result

Tags: php, regex, perl

This is some kind of academic question, I just wondering if it is possible to capture a group (f.e. with usage of PHP preg_match() function) with substring excluded in result. I'm interested in achieving this on regex level. Let me explain, what I'm talking about.

F.e., I have source string like:

```
...   
... needed_NUMERIC_substr_1 not_needed_ALPHA_substr need_NUMERIC_substr2 ...  
...
```

Is it possible to write regexp which will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => %**NOT_IMPORTANT_THAT_WILL_BE_HERE**%
    [1] => needed_NUMERIC_substr_1 need_NUMERIC_substr2
)
```

**I understand, that it is possible to match both needed strings separately with different capturing groups and then to perform any required action in the code.** This is just academic interest.

I thought about using **conditional subpatterns** or **lookahead** and **lookbehind** zero-width assertions, but wasn't able to found solution. If it is possible, how it could be achieved?

Comment: I doubt it... It's illogical to work that way because your capture group matched whole text. It's `match`, not `match_and_postprocess` .)

Comment: Thx @Vyktor, agree that this is illogical and too complex way. But I still wonder :).

Comment: @Shiplu, this isn't native homework. It's my own academic interest.

Comment: I've posted an answer let's see whether they lynch me .))

Comment: @Vyktor No reason for lynch :). It is correct for preg_match(). But what about regex level. Let see what will say regex gurus.

Comment: When you use `preg_replace` (resp. `s///` in perl) it sure is possible :)

Comment: @Milkywayfarer I added the homework tag so that you get more explanation and thoughts, not only *the correct answer*.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question... Given an input string `123abc456` you want a result string `123456`?

Comment: @Shiplu Thx for explanation. I'll notice this for the future questions.

Comment: @Arjan yes, this is that I want. But solve this only with regex. Digits and letters  used for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.

`preg_match` doesn't provide any options how to join matched groups together or erase (replace with empty string) part of matched text.

Comment: What about regex level? Is it completely non-solvable on it?

Comment: @Milkywayfarer I'm sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean, if it is possible to add some logic inside regex? I know there are conditional subpaterns. May be it could be achieved somehow with them or other advanced regex features.

Comment: AFAIK not with PCRE, there sure is kind of regexp that would allow it (or you may implement it).

Answer (score 1):

Since the question really seems to be how to get `123456` from the input string `123abc456`, I wouldn't use `preg_match`. Instead I would use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and replace everything that is not a digit with the empty string, so they effectively get removed.

```
$string = '123abc456';
$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string);
echo $result; // prints 123456
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, but question is about how to do it on regex level. If it is possible in principle...

Comment: @Milkywayfarer, actually, `preg_replace` uses a regex. See my updated answer.

Comment: thx I see, and clearly understand this approach, and that this is usual way and correct practical solution. But my interest is non-practic, it is academic. I want to clarify if it is possible to solve this only with regex. F.e. write such regex, which will match '123abc456' and return only '123456' in one of the capturing groups.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Capturing groups capture only continues substrings of the input string (or nothing at all).

Comment: Thx. Seems it is really impossible votes for this now are: 4:0.